# Issues using css fixed position popup

Tags: css, popup

We are using a slightly unorthodox method using table to fire up our popups. This has been working fine in the sense that it helps us:

1. avoid any post back issues.
2. popup expands depending upon the contents but not transcending the view port.
3. Both, Vertical and horizontal scroll bars show up as and when required.
4. If you minimize the browser the scroll bar appears as and when needed.

here is the code:

```
<table bgcolor="white" style="position:fixed; margin-top:40px;  display:block; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0); max-width:80%; max-height:70%; overflow:auto " border="3" class="simpleroundshadow" >
      <tr>

                        <td align="center" style="padding:30px;"> 

                            <div>
                            contents:<br>

                            </div>


   </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

you can see this in action here: 
http://atldunia.com/youtube/FixedPosPopup.htm

The issues we have is :

1. We are unable to auto align the Close Popup Button to the right side.
2. Also, we need a Close Popup Button on the bottom of the popup as well.

As you can notice that the Close button on top  is not affected by the scrolling.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a table is very wrong if am asked, but here is something I worked out, you have to modify the height of the div in the content row. I added the below code to the div:

```
height: 340px ; overflow: scroll;
```

I also removed the styles from the input and floated it to the right. Here is the complete code:

```
<table bgcolor="white" style="position:fixed; margin-top:40px;  display:block; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0); max-width:80%; max-height:70%; overflow:auto " border="3" class="simpleroundshadow" >
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input  type="submit" style="float: right;" value="Close popup" name="B3" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="center">
                            <div style="height: 340px ; overflow: scroll;">
                            contents:<br>
contents:
Please view the page source.
It is only a few lines
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 

                              contents:
Please view the page source.
It is only a few lines
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 

                            </div>
   </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
```

I hope this helps, in case you are confused, here is a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJaeMR)

Comment: Thanks to Bliss for replying . But this doesn't work . The button disappears with the scroll. I have updated to show the this functionality- close button that wont disappear; your button that disappears in the scroll.  http://atldunia.com/youtube/FixedPosPopup.htm

Comment: You reset the height of the inner div to 1500px? It can't work with that height. Check the pen I replied with and take a close look at it to see what I changed. The height of the div should be set to a pixel that would not make the table scroll. And also, the div should have the overflow: scroll; style too

Comment: Bliss  thanks. div height 1500 px is just an example to show V and H scroll bars. This popup would adjust AND DOES ADJUST  to the contents.  Ideally div would not have any ht or wd . also, height: 340px is not what we are looking for. We are not looking to wrap our contents around any fixed px. You might want to play around with the code to see what I mean.